# xcode Caching images for images in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, caching, uiimage

I have a list of images retrieve from .xml file and these images are images link from the server       e.g. " www.seeimage.com/rice.png"

I am parsing the images everytime I went to that page

```
-(void)viewdidload{
for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.foodItems count];i++) {
   NSURL *ZensaiimageSmallURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ZensaiPLUitems.ZensaiimageSmallURL];
   NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", ZensaiimageSmallURL];
   NSData *simageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ZensaiimageSmallURL];
   UIImage *itemSmallimage = [UIImage imageWithData:simageData];
   [zenbutton2 setImage:itemSmallimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [scrollView addSubview:zenbutton2];
  }
}
```

i have been trying out on this tutorial : http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/13315-image-caching-tutorial.html

but i have no idea on how to implement this in my work.

any idea on how to cache them on the first run and whenever i return to that view ?

i don't want to rerun this method to retrive the images from the website everytime i come to this view.

it takes quite some time to init the images from the website to my UIButton before populating them to the scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to retrieve the images from the website every time then you can download it once and store them e.g. into NSMutableDictionary . And access it whenever you want.

OR

Parse those images in separate thread so that your table view or scroll view will not get paused.